# How to highlight the thumbnail image when the hero image comes into viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, thumbnails, viewport

I am trying implement a functionality where-in the respective thumbnail of the hero image gets highlighted when that image has crossed 50% and is in the view-port. And also make the thumbnails sticky so that user can click on it to navigate to the respective image.

Am trying to do this by jQuery without using any Bootstrap framework, a reference to understand this better is as seen in the below site.
I am looking to implement the same functionality for my site as well.

I am aware that we can **.visible()** to check if the image is visible, but here am looking to highlight the corresponding thumbnail of the hero image as well.

https://www.everlane.com/products/mens-cotton-crew-stone?collection=mens-all

Any suggestions/ideas would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you can use the index of an array to recognize the thumbnail with its respective hero image. As you told in the post, you knew the logic of identifying the hero image. So you need to just use the same index to find thumbnail and add some `selected` class to it with border css.